# Avoid image stretch within a CSS octagon container

Tags: html, css

When I updated the octagon's background image, it seems to have stretched it. Before, with the same CSS and a different image, it was normal.

**Here is the original photo. As you can see, it is NOT stretched:**

[image: Original Picture]

**Here is the octagon photo that is stretched:**

[image]

**Here is all the code affecting the octagon image:**

```css
img[Attributes Style] {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.octo {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.octo1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.octo,
.octo div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="octo">
    <div class="octo1">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5voQJ.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: upload a square image.

Comment: This is for my Portfolio. I want an Octagonal Image for design.

Comment: the source image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `<img>`, include the image as a `background-image` for a `<span>` element, and use `background-size: cover` on it. To position the image, adjust the `background-position` values.

```css
.octo-image {
     display: block;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background-position: center center;
     background-size: cover;
}

* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

.octo {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.octo1 {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.octo, .octo div {
     margin: 0 auto;
     transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="octo">
     <div class="octo1">
          <span class="octo-image" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5voQJ.jpg')"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use `<img>` with `object-fit: cover` as well, but then you have to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/) to support IE11 and older:

```css
.octo-image {
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     object-fit: cover;
     object-position: center center;
}

* {
     box-sizing: border-box;
}

.octo {
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.octo1 {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.octo, .octo div {
     margin: 0 auto;
     transform-origin: 50% 50%;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="octo">
     <div class="octo1">
          <img class="octo-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5voQJ.jpg"></span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a square source image, not a landscape rectangle. Specifying the height and width of an image force it to be a square. Your image will get squished on the horizontal and stretched on the vertical since it is a landscape image. This has nothing to do with your octagon styling. See my below example:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiEvT.png" height="300" width="300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you can't use a background image you could use the `clip-path` property to draw the octagon with a **cleaner** markup and a **full-responsive** behaviour

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gKvKqe)

Markup

```
<figure>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5voQJ.jpg" alt=""/>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
/*
 * The outer wrapper defines the shape and hides the overflow of the
 * inner image. The max-width ensures the responsiveness.
 */
figure {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 70% 0%, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 
                     70% 100%, 30% 100%, 0% 70%, 0% 30%);
}

/* 
 * This pseudoelement ensures to keep the correct aspect ratio 
 * through the padding-bottom property. Since the image should be 
 * squared, the padding must be 100% of the element width
 */
figure::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

/*
 * Finally the image must be properly centered (it requires some 
 * adjustment if the subject it's not aligned in its canvas), 
 * the height is 100% of its container but the width is not 
 * specified so the image can scale, keeping its natural 
 * aspect ratio 
 */
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

---

**Final result**

[image]